# .NET ODataController class to return collection of type strutcurally unrelated to type for controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata

I have a class, `MyClassController` that inherits from `ODataController`. I've been able to use the "automagic" routing for access to properties of scaler collections types using, e.g., `/path/to/MyClass(100)/SomeProperty`. I now need to return a collection of a class that's structurally unrelated to `MyClass` (i.e., there are no references connecting the two classes) but logically, there's a relationship between the two. I'd like to be able to do something like `GET`ting `/path/to/MyClass(100)/RelatedThings/`. How can I set that up? I'm setting up `MyClass` and its related classes using `ODataConventionModelBuilder.EntitySet<>` in the `Application_Start`.

I'm using Microsoft.OData.Core 6.13.0 (OData 4.0).

**edit:** I left out some details from this question that I didn't realize were relevant about some of the design decisions I'd made elsewhere in the application, so I accepted the answer that best solves this problem without taking those details into account. I ended up making a bound OData function in the MyClass controller that returned the related things. I found if I didn't include the namespace or a trailing slash, the HTTP requested yielded error. That is, `/path/to/MyClass(100)/Default.RelatingThings/` works. I'm looking into ways to removing the need for the trailing slash and the namespace. (*edit*: Call `config.EnableUnqualifiedNameCall(true)` when setting up your OData routing; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35156885/1102726.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OData routes do not have to match the relationships in your storage schema; i.e., the lack of a structural relationship is irrelevant. Just add a property to `MyClass` similar to the following:

```
public ICollection<Thing> RelatedThings { get; set; }
```

Then define an action method for the property:

```
public IQueryable<Thing> GetRelatedThings([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    // Fill-in data access logic.
}
```

You won't be to request `/path/to/MyClass(100)?$expand=RelatedThings`, but you will be able to request `/path/to/MyClass(100)/RelatedThings` as you desire.

Comment: I did consider that, but I'd like to keep the way the domain objects works consistent between similar domain objects. If I were to change the data model the way you're suggesting, it would be the only place in our model where a reference from an automatically-hydrated plain old CLR object has a reference to an object that's not. (Some of our domain objects come from NHibernate and others from JSON HTTP services.) I'm also very much opposed to have a property with a comment that says, "never use this property; it's just here so OData doesn't complain."

Comment: The entities and relationships exposed by your OData service do not have to directly match the objects and relationships in your storage schema(s). Model the storage objects and OData entities separately and use a library like AutoMapper to transform between the 2 models. This approach will let you expose the logical relationship between `MyClass` and `RelatedThings` without exposing any of the details of how or where the objects are stored.

Comment: I would like them too, however. This lets my ORM handle the pagination rather and filtering rather than having the ORM hydrate the entire result set. I also don't want to add yet another representation of the data. Domain objects, data transfer objects for business logic operations, and view models are kind of enough, especially when then reason I'd be adding yet another representation is as a workaround for what really is a routing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you data is structurally unrelated you won't be able to expand to your related entities.  There is an oData extension for data-aggregation, joins

using the extension it would look something like:

```
~/$crossjoin(Products,Sales)
                     ?$expand=Products($select=Name),Sales($select=Amount)
                     &$filter=Products/ID eq Sales/ProductID
```

you can see a full sample of [Cross Joining in OData](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_Toc378326314)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not familiar with OData cross joins, but this seems too complicated given what I want to do. I don't want to get all of the products and all of the sales. I only want to get the sales for a specific product. In your example, I'd be `GET`ting `/path/to/$crossjoin(Product,Sales)?$filter=Products/ID eq Sales/ProductID and Products/ID = 2358`. Is there no way to use the `/path/to/Product(2358)/`? I could also create a new controller for Sales, but I would want to make sure that the product ID was required. 

By the way, I love your handle and avatar.

Comment: you can do it in two requests, you can make a request to your class and then make another request to your child class where the other id matches and then just join your results in javascript or where ever your consuming the data, p.s yeah short circuit is a great movie

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the ID from the first class a mandatory parameter of the second class. I tried making a function, and wound up checking out https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataFunctionSample/FunctionSample/Controllers/ProductsController.cs. (I don't recall how I found that, but it's very useful!)

Anyway, if I were to make a `RelatedThingsController` with an `IQueryable<RelatedThing> Get()` method, is there a way add a required parameter for the parent ID?

Comment: I did look at making an OData function to return the `RelatedThing` collection in the `MyClassController`, but I can't figure out how to get rid of that `Default.` namespace, but that might also be an option.

Comment: Check out this link you might be able to create an action filter that joins the entities afterwards http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953323/modify-odata-results-after-query